# Создавать разное значение атрибута name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, ajax-load

есть задача создать сайт где пользователь с ролью "преподаватель" может создавать свои тесты, на странице где создаются вопросы и ответы, нужно сделать изначально только форму для одного вопроса, а если преподаватель захочет добавить ещё n-ное количество форм, под вопросом должна быть кнопка "добавить вопрос" и под первой формой должна создаваться форма для 2 вопроса, и это я ещё как-то могу сделать, но как создать разное значение для вопросов, и как убирать кнопку перед тем как будет создана следующая форма с кнопкой, скорее всего это можно сделать на ajax

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос то, что уже удалось реализовать, либо упрощенный прототип.

Comment: Всё так же. Возможно можно как-то через файловый документ это делать, по типу( вверху название теста, краткое описание, картинка, и файл который хранит в себе тесты если так можно